# Убрать лишние слова в R

Tags: r

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать слова из одной переменной, которые соответствуют словам  в другой переменной?

**К примеру:**

Есть нужные слова:

```
words <- с("надо","купить","кошачий","корм","и","надо","купить","по","пять","кило","яблок","и","огурцов")
```

И есть ненужные слова:

```
unnecessary_words <- c("по","и","надо")
```

**И должно получиться так:**

```
[1] "купить"  "кошачий"  "корм"  "купить"  "пять"  "кило"  "яблок"  "огурцов"
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
setdiff(words,unnecessary_words)
```

Но похожие слова теряются:

```
[1] "купить"  "кошачий" "корм"    "пять"    "кило"    "яблок"   "огурцов"
```

Буду сильно благодарен за помощь! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#один из вариантов решения
words  <- c("надо", "купить", "кошачий", "корм", "и", "надо", "купить", "по", "пять", "кило", "яблок", "и", "огурцов")
u_words  <- c("по", "и", "надо")

rslt  <- words[! words %in% u_words]

> words
 [1] "надо"    "купить"  "кошачий" "корм"    "и"       "надо"    "купить"  "по"      "пять"    "кило"    "яблок"   "и"       "огурцов"
> u_words
[1] "по"   "и"    "надо"
> rslt
[1] "купить"  "кошачий" "корм"    "купить"  "пять"    "кило"    "яблок"   "огурцов"
```